# Given two arrays, find the number of elements greater

Tags: arrays, algorithm

This was the interview question I had from a tech company. I got it wrong, which I think doomed my chances, but I honestly I still cannot figure out the answer... here's the question. Assume that all elements of the sequence are unique.

We have two finite sequences: X={Xi}, Y={Yi} where Yi is a sub-sequence of Xi.

Let's write them as separate arrays: [X1, X2, ..., Xn], [Y1, Y2, ..., Yk] where n is the length of X, k is the length of Y, and obviously, since Y is a sub-sequence of X, we have n>=k.

For instance

```
X=[1, 10, 5, 7, 11, -4, 9, 5]
y=[10, 7, -4, 9]
```

Then for each element in Y, we want to find the number of elements in X which **1) appear after that element** and **2) greater than that element**.

Using the example above

```
X=[1, 10, 5, 7, 11, -4, 9, 5]
y=[10, 7, -4, 9]
ans=[1, 2, 2, 0]

explanation:

the first element of ans is 1 because only 11 appears after 10 and greater than 10 in X, 
so there's only 1 element

second element of ans is 2 since 11, 9 both appear after 7 in X, so there are 2 elements 
that appear after 7 and greater than 7. 

the third element of ans is also 2 since 9, 5 appear after -4 and are both greater than 
-4 in X. 

the fourth element is 0 since no element in X appears after and greater than 9.
```

The interviewer wanted me to solve it in O(N) time complexity where N is the length of X. I did not find how.

Anybody has an idea?

Comment: Couldn't there be more than one answer if duplicates are allowed?

Comment: @גלעד ברקן  Thanks for pointing out. I should've added that all elements are unique.

Comment: I think its impossible, for a example If x=y then we want to know how many number are after that element, its kind of sorting, because for each element we want to know how many numbers and we should check all other element and repeat it for whole array, and its impossible to solve it for O(N)
If we can so there should be algoritm for sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If have an algorithm that can solve this problem, then by setting `Y = X`, you can make it provide enough information to sort `X` without any further comparisons among elements in `X`.  Therefore, you can't do this in linear time under the usual assumptions, i.e., arbitrary integers in `X` that you can do operations on in constant time, but no constant bound on their size.

You can do it in O(N log N) time pretty easily by walking backwards through `X` and maintaining an order statistic tree of the elements seen so far.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree

Comment: I implemented O(N log N) algorithm during the interview during priority queue, but I was told that there's a way to make it O(N).

Comment: The hint I was given was use a stack, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Were you given any other constraints, like the elements in X are sequential or dense?  Presumably you were told they're all unique or the solution is ambiguous.

Comment: Yes, all elements of the sequence are unique. I forgot to add that in the original post, so I modified it just now.

Comment: idk. The hints I was given are that 

1) X, Y are in the same order since Y is a sub-sequence.
2) Think of a way to make use of previous 'counts'
3) Use stack

Answer (score -1):

I think it's impossible same as it's impossible for sorting and here is the reason

For solving this we should save state for previous calculation in limited number variable, for example store addition, subtraction or multiply.
So if there is a big number in `A` thats not in `B` its very clear it's not usefull at all, and we already know the only possible solution is to save previous state in limited variable, So we can't have numbers that related only to item in `A`.

So far we know to solve this is we should figure out the saving state algorithm, for saving state we can only store some number that represent for all previous numbers for current element in `Y` all of these calculation its not helping because we dont know the next item in `Y` (for example the current number is `-1000` and next number is `3000` and other number in `X` is 1,2,3). so because of that we cant have any stored number that related to current element in `Y`. also we cant have any number that's not related to `Y`(as its usefull at all)