# Given two arrays, find the next greater element

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I asked the question in [Given two arrays, find the number of elements greater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876480/given-two-arrays-find-the-number-of-elements-greater) then I realized that I stated it completely wrong, so I'll ask it again.

We have two finite sequences: X={Xi}, Y={Yi} where Yi is a sub-sequence of Xi.

Let's write them as separate arrays: [X1, X2, ..., Xn], [Y1, Y2, ..., Yk] where n is the length of X, k is the length of Y, and obviously, since Y is a sub-sequence of X, we have n>=k.

For instance

```
X=[1, 10, 5, 7, 11, -4, 9, 5]
y=[10, 7, -4, 9]
```

Then for each element in Y, we want to find the the first element in X which 1) appear after that element and 2) greater than that element. If there's no such element, we just use -1

Using the example above

```
X=[1, 10, 5, 7, 11, -4, 9, 5]
y=[10, 7, -4, 9]
ans=[11, 11, 9, -1]
```

explanation:

the first element of ans is 11 because only 11 is the first number that appears after 10 and greater than 10 in X

second element of ans is also 11 since 11 is the first number that appears after 7 in X.

the third element of ans is also 9 since 9 is the first number that appears after -4 and are both greater than -4

the fourth element is -1 since no element in X appears after and greater than 9.

The question is to solve it in O(N) time complexity where N is the length of X. Anybody has an idea?

Comment: Why isnt the answer [11, 11, 7, 11]?

Comment: The first number bigger than -4 and indexed after the value -4 is 9. There is no number bigger than 9 after 9 in X. It seems to make sense

Comment: Is this a python question?

Comment: Are the elements in `Y` always arranged such that the elements are in the same order as they appear in `X`?

Comment: Here's a solution https://leetcode.com/problems/next-greater-element-i/discuss/277781/c++-O(m+n)-solution-using-stack (It says O(m + n) but this is O(N) as you requested since the larger sequence is length N.)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element-in-same-order-as-input/    got it